# How can I make my mobile navbar responsive and use media queries?

Tags: html, css

**1)** On mobile my top navigation bar looks like [this](https://ibb.co/5r8MnLY). As you can see depending on the logo size the navigation bar logo which is the three horizontal lines automatically adjusts. I just want it to be in the middle right hand size. For example like [this](https://ibb.co/MhS2Rz2) no matter what the navbrand logo size is. How can I do this?

**2)** When the top navigation bar goes to mobile view again as you can see [here](https://ibb.co/5r8MnLY). How can I make the phone number and email text be in the centre in a more responsive way? From doing research I was looking at something called media queries. Does anyone have any good links for this?

Here is my site code if you require additional coding to look at https://github.com/liamdocherty/courier.

```css
    /**
     * Header
     */
    .header {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 5;
    }

    .header-toparea {
      background: #333333;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .header-topinfo ul {
      padding-left: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .header-topinfo ul li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 0 17px;
      padding: 2px 0;
    }

    .header-topinfo ul li:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    .header-topinfo ul li:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .header-topinfo ul li i {
      margin-right: 10px;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    .header-topinfo ul li a {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .header-topinfo ul li a:hover {
      color: #3423A6;
    }

    .header-topsocial {
      text-align: right;
    }

    .header-topsocial ul {
      padding-left: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .header-topsocial ul li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 6px;
      padding: 2px 0;
    }

    .header-topsocial ul li:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    .header-topsocial ul li:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .header-topsocial ul li a {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .header-topsocial ul li a:hover {
      color: #3423A6;
    }

    .header-bottomarea {
      background: #ffffff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      box-shadow: 5px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      z-index: 3;
      position: relative;
    }

    .header-bottominner {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
      position: relative;
    }

    .header-bottominner .tm-navigation {
      text-align: right;
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .header-logo a {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .header-icons {
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .header-icons ul {
      padding-left: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .header-icons ul li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 7px;
    }

    .header-icons ul li:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    .header-icons ul li:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .header-icons ul li a {
      color: #444444;
      font-size: 21px;
    }

    .header-icons ul li a:hover {
      color: #3423A6;
    }

    .header-searchbox {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: #ffffff;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      z-index: -1;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

    .header-searchbox .search-close {
      padding: 0;
      color: #333333;
      font-size: 20px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .header-searchbox .search-close i {
      line-height: 50px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .header-searchbox .search-close:hover {
      color: #3423A6;
    }

    .header-searchbox.is-visible {
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .header-searchinner {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: -25px;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
      transform: translateY(-100%);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .header-searchform {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .header-searchform input {
      height: 45px;
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    .header-searchbox.is-visible .header-searchinner {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0);
      transform: translateY(0);
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      .header-logo {
        padding: 15px 0;
      }
      .header-icons {
        padding-right: 45px;
      }
      .header-searchbox.is-visible {
        z-index: 3;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .header-topinfo ul li {
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }
      .header-logo {
        padding: 15px 0;
      }
      .header-icons {
        padding-right: 45px;
      }
      .header-searchbox.is-visible {
        z-index: 3;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
      .header-topsocial {
        text-align: left;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .header-logo {
        max-width: 130px;
        padding: 22px 0;
      }
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-bar {
      min-height: 0;
      padding: 0;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal {
      color: #444444;
      font-size: 22px !important;
      padding: 0;
      text-indent: 0;
      z-index: 99;
      margin-top: -45px;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav {
      background: #3423A6;
      background: #3423A6;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav > ul {
      max-height: 196px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav > ul li a {
      padding: 7px 5%;
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav > ul li a.mean-expand {
      padding: 3px 6px !important;
      height: 32px;
      line-height: 32px;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav > ul li a.mean-expand:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav > ul li li a {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav > ul li ul li a {
      padding: 7px 10%;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav > ul li ul ul li a {
      padding: 7px 15%;
    }

    .header-mobilemenu .mean-container .mean-nav > ul li ul ul ul li a {
      padding: 7px 20%;
    }

    .header.sticky-active .header-bottomarea {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 99;
      -webkit-animation: slideInDown 0.5s ease-in-out 0s 1 both;
      animation: slideInDown 0.5s ease-in-out 0s 1 both;
    }
```

```html
    <!-- Header Top Area -->
               <div class="header-toparea">
                   <div class="container">
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-12">
                               <div class="header-topinfo">
                                   <ul>
                                       <li><a href="tel://07828882838"><i class="flaticon-phone-call"></i>
                                               07828882838</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="mailto://contact@example.com"><i class="flaticon-envelope"></i>
                                               contact@example.com</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-12">
                               <div class="header-topsocial">
                                   <ul>
                                       <li><a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                       <li><a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <!--// Header Top Area -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For issue-1 You have to change navigation markup also please note you need to change js for mobile navigation. One suggestion from my side since you are using bootstrap in your website you can use bootstrap navigation here is the [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/)

```
<!-- Header Bottom Area -->
        <div class="header-bottomarea">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-bottominner">
                    <div class="header-logo">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="assets/images/logo/same-day-delivery2.png" alt="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="tm-navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index-2.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="header-searchbox">
                        <div class="header-searchinner">
                            <form action="#" class="header-searchform">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter search keyword..">
                            </form>
                            <button class="search-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-mobilemenu clearfix">
                        <div class="tm-mobilenav"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--// Header Bottom Area -->
```

And css need to be change `margin-top: -45px;` to `margin-top: -9px;`

```
.header-mobilemenu .mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal {
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 22px !important;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
```

For issue-2 you need to write style in media query so that those chunk of code only visible for small device. here i have added `display:block` in the `li` so `li` takes 100% width and then i have make the content center by using `text-align:center`

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 580px) {
        .header-topinfo ul li{
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .header-topsocial ul{
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will be helpful for You

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've tried adding the work to my code and I think I probably added it incorrectly. Any chance you could add this to my GitHub please? As when I tried to test the code I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hi one another thing, when the shrinks when I click on the icon to make the navbar links appear nothing happens? No links show